# eyed3 mp3 metadata in python

Tags: python, eyed3

```
import eyed3

filename = "/home/chris/Music/Αναστάσιμα τροπάρια ή άλλα τροπάρια Δεσποτικών, Θεομητορικών ή άλλων εορτών Αγίων/ΑΓΙΑ ΣΚΕΠΗ.mp3"
filename2 = "/home/chris/Music/Αναστάσιμα τροπάρια ή άλλα τροπάρια Δεσποτικών, Θεομητορικών ή άλλων εορτών Αγίων/ΑΓΙΟΙ ΑΓΓΕΛΟΙ.mp3"
filename3 = "/home/chris/Documents/Python/Papinhio player/version 2.1/diskets box/songs/mp3/Μιχάλης Χατζηγιάννης - Που Είναι Η Αγάπη - Official Audio Release.mp3"
audiofile = eyed3.load(filename3)
audiofile.tag.artist = "Artist"

audiofile.tag.save()
```

The third mp3 file works correct.
It was created from python with AudioSegment module (

command that creates the file:

```
self.extension = self.sound_imported_filename.split(".")[-1]
        self.filename = self.sound_imported_filename.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
        self.audio = AudioSegment.from_file(self.sound_imported_filename, format=self.extension)
        self.audio_info = mediainfo(self.sound_imported_filename)
self.audio.export("/home/chris/Documents/Python/Papinhio player/version 2.1/diskets box/songs/mp3/"+self.filename+".mp3", format="mp3")
```

The first two mp3 files was downloaded from youtube-to-mp3.com i think (I am not sure).

The problem is that with the first two files i get this error:

```
root@chris-pc:/home/chris/Documents/Python/Papinhio player/version 2.1/main/test# python3.6 metadata.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "metadata.py", line 7, in <module>
    audiofile.tag.artist = "Artist"
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'artist'
```

What's wrong with the first two mp3 files?

I have uploaded the first mp3 file for use in [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UAiC0MkLj7S-Bw1QjAkPtPSMmVoNAhMc/view?usp=sharing)

**Edit:**

```
import eyed3
from pydub.audio_segment import AudioSegment

filename1 = "/home/chris/Music/Αναστάσιμα τροπάρια ή άλλα τροπάρια Δεσποτικών, Θεομητορικών ή άλλων εορτών Αγίων/ΑΓΙΑ ΣΚΕΠΗ.mp3"
filename2 = "/home/chris/Music/Αναστάσιμα τροπάρια ή άλλα τροπάρια Δεσποτικών, Θεομητορικών ή άλλων εορτών Αγίων/ΑΓΙΟΙ ΑΓΓΕΛΟΙ.mp3"
filename3 = "/home/chris/Documents/Python/Papinhio player/version 2.1/diskets box/songs/mp3/Μιχάλης Χατζηγιάννης - Που Είναι Η Αγάπη - Official Audio Release.mp3"

try:
    audiofile = eyed3.load(filename2)
    audiofile.tag.artist = "Artist"
    audiofile.tag.save()
except:
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(filename2, format="mp3")
    audio.export(filename2, format="mp3",bitrate="128.0")
    audiofile = eyed3.load(filename2)
    audiofile.tag.artist = "Artist"
    audiofile.tag.save()
```

The above code works, but i don't know why the first one does not.

Comment: Using the command line for `eyeD3` for the first file worked

Comment: https://github.com/nicfit/eyeD3/issues/153